# How to wait for user to complete the data entry before processing with waithandle

Tags: c#, waithandle

I have UI which allows user to enter data, every time when the user enter a data I raise an event saying data changed at this location and put it in a queue. I have a background thread which listens to the events with ***waithandle*** with ***waitany***. Every time data changes I force an action for all items in the queue. It works fine. The problem is that when user enters two values, there will be two change events. Two elements in the queue, but the first event gets first and immediately forces an action and at that time there was only one item in the queue. Next event comes, it will process next item from queue. 99% of the time the process process one event from queue because of the slowness of the human data entry the fastness of the event processing. Just wondering if there is a way, I could put some logic around the processing event to wait a bit and then process?

The waithandle part

```
switch(WaitHandle.WaitAny(myhandles))
{
   case event.ProcessEvent:
        ProcessEvents();
        break;
   ...
}
```

In the process event

```
private void ProcessEvents()
{
  while(eventQueue.Count > 0)
  {
     //dequeue event
     //process the given event
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: What to the handles represent? Changes in different locations in the UI? If so, why do you need many if you're waiting on all of them? Also, what exactly should happen when two events are queued up? You seem to be processing everything in the queue by design.

Comment: I have only 2 events, one is for data change and another one UI goes out of scope. So I am waiting on any available one to show up. Yes I need to process all the events as they show up.-ty